# How to load Datatables ajax data only when content has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

i have a datatable table with an `setInterval` function to load every 1 sec the content. My Problem is, that the Chrome Browser network cache is going to increase with every load. Sometimes just a few kb but if there is more to load i.e. 200 lines than it will load every time i.e. 2 MB. This will increase the memory usage of this tab and the chrome in general.

I have php to generate a json based on a mysql database call. This data can change i.e. update, delete or add. My time stamp is the column `date_update`

Is there a way to load all data on initial load and than only when content has changed (`date_update` is greater than last generated timestamp)? Something like an heartbeat or beacon function, to check if there is content changed older than XY timestamp and if so, load it?

I am using this regular function:

```
var MyTable = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            url: './includes/myDataFile.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        paging: false,
        scrollY: 250,
        sort:   true,
        filter: false,
        select: { style: 'single'},
        width: '100%',
        'columns': [
            {
                'data': 'id'
            },
            {
                'data': 'name'
            },
            {
                'data': 'start'
            },
            {
                'data': 'end'
            },
            {
                'data': 'count'
            },
            {
                'data': 'status'
            },
{
                'data': 'date_update',
                 visible: false
            }
        ],

    });


    setInterval(function() {
        $('#MyTable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false); // user paging is not reset on reload
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Which content changed?

Comment: The database table content. Maybe there was an add, update or delete. I generate a json via php with content from mysql database.

Comment: To track the realtime data  change I have used the strong package SignalR with .NET but i think its not available for PHP.

Comment: First you obviously have to decouple the ajax request and the table update. Next, determine on the server which records have changed and only send back those. If you want actual realtime updates, you'll have to use a solution like [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Not sure if there exist any simpler methods... but with minimal php knowledge the basic idea would be to write a trigger on your table.. saying when ever there is a change in your table write this change log into a new table called with DateTime stamp. Also make sure you maintain a date time stamp on your UI side to indicate which version of data you have.. So now you can regularly check the database in intervals by passing this date time stamp... if there is new entry then trigger a ` $('#MyTable').DataTable().draw()`

Comment: @RajshekarReddy thanks, I haven't thought about the trigger. I could always ping against the table ('UPDATES') and if there is a change, i do a load from the initial table. I will test this.

Comment: Perhaps you can use push notifications to alert the browser that the database has changed? https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

Comment: @Kokodoko no, this makes the user click it away and wondering why there is nothing been updated. Users are lazy..

Comment: @Cyber it would also be better on performance if you can pass around only the new/updated records and make minimal data transfer over the wire.. Also something which `kokodoko` suggest is also good.. instead of continuous ping to your database its better to notify the browser when ever there is a change and then just do one ajax call..

Comment: @Cyber I meant that your client-side script will respond to the notification and then update the table. (you don't have to show a notification box to the user, only the script responds). Take a look at: https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start